# Is it possible for a Javascript bookmarklet to read its own name?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I would like some of my bookmarklets to adjust their behavior based on their current name.

For example, I'd like to edit a bookmarklet I use, so that it would increment the last integer in the current URL by 24 if it was named "+24", or decrement it by 10 if it was named "-10".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not possible. At least in decent browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Using [`window.location`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp) object you can get information about current URL and redirect to a new one.

Comment: I don't need the URL. What I want is the name the user has given to the bookmarklet.